# OOP GUI, Template C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm a game designer coming from a Basic-like programming language and moving to C++.
For a new game I'd like to have a gui programmed using OOP.

My gui currently consists of a **gui**-class (the outer wrapper), a **g_element**-class (the middle wrapper containing all the common attributes) and a **button**-class (overriding and extending the g_element-class).

The problem is I'm getting the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   std::list,class std::allocator > > gui
>
> > ::el_stack"(?el_stack@?$gui@V?$g_element@Vbutton@@@@@@2V?$list@V?$g_element@Vbutton@@@@V?$allocator@V?$g_element@Vbutton@@@@@std@@@std@@A)

I really think that this error is not the only problem - I might have a completely wrong approach for this whole thing. I'm also not really sure about that template-thing - I thought I'd be able to expand my g_element-class with gui-elements later (i.e. buttons, sliders, windows...) - but give me a hint if there's something that I can optimise.

Here is my gui.cpp file (so far):

```
using namespace std;

template <class GUI_ELEMENT> class gui {

protected:
    void add_to_stack(GUI_ELEMENT elem) {
        // The error comes from here..
        // I wanted a list of all my g_elements (buttons) 
        el_stack.push_back(elem);
        printf("size now: %d", el_stack.size());
    }

    unsigned int get_stack_size() {
        return el_stack.size();
    }

public:
    static list<GUI_ELEMENT>     el_stack;  // The elements list 

    void render() {
        // here, I'd like to iterate over all i.e. buttons to draw them
    }
};


template <class GUI_ELEMENT> class g_element : public    gui<g_element<GUI_ELEMENT> >{

private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float h;

public:
    void set_width(float width) {
        this->w = width;
    }

    float get_width() {
         return this->w;
    }
};

class button : public g_element<button> {

protected:
    char* caption; 

public:
    button(float x, float y, float w, float h, char* caption) {
        this->set_width(w);
        this->set_caption(caption);
        this->add_to_stack(*this);
    }

    void set_caption(char* caption) {
        this->caption = caption;
    }

    char* get_caption()  {
        return this->caption;
    }

};
```

I'd like to use my gui like so:

```
// Create a few test buttons
button b1(50, 50, 100, 50, "Test");
b1.set_width(150);
float s = b1.get_width();
printf("size w: %f", s);
printf("\ncaption: %s", b1.get_caption());

button b2(50, 50, 100, 50, "Test");
button b3(50, 50, 100, 50, "Test2");
button b4(50, 50, 100, 50, "Test3");

// Rendering currently (all buttons at once)
gui<button> G;
G.render();
// but this would be nicer:
gui::render_buttons()
// or
gui<button>::render()
```

Is there somebody who might help me? Really big thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider using [Qt](http://qt.io)? It is a GUI toolkit for (and in) C++

Comment: It is just a very simple GUI for an ingame level editor - I know, it may be a little exaggerated writing a GUI myself, but we only need a few functions so that Qt is too much.

Comment: You can use very few features of Qt, and most Qt users are doing that. You might also look into [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) or [FOX toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) but I still recommend Qt.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this option, too. I may be checking this out later when I won't be able to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

All static fields should be defined outside of the class definition. In your case you have to add these lines of code after a class definition:

```
template<class GUI_ELEMENT>
list<GUI_ELEMENT> gui<GUI_ELEMENT>::el_stack;
```

Comment: Thanks, now the stack itself is filling up, but in my render-method the result is zero. 

    void render() {
  printf("stack size: %d", get_stack_size());
 }

How would you render all the button-instances?

Comment: Note, that this static stack won't be shared across all template instantiations. This means that you will have two distinct stacks for gui<button> and gui<check_button> and maybe this is the reason why you have an empty stack - you just populate one and trying to render another one.

Comment: Okay.. How would you change it to achieve what I'd like to do?